# Redirect users with "." (dot) in their username and replace with "-" (dash) to correct profile

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, login, username

Im having problem with usernames that have '.' (dot) in their username and throwing 404 when try to access their profile page in front end. Can we replace this '.' (dot) with '-' (dash) because working url is with a '.'(dash).

The system only generates link with user name ex: domain.com/members/[username automatically added]

but some username includes '.' (dot) which system dont recognize.

Ex:
domain.com/members/user.name  -> 404

domain.com/members/user-name  -> working

Comment: how are you creating users with a dot in their name? What is `/members`?

Comment: Im using a user directory plugin which lists users in front end on a page (Members). when i look at wordpress dashboard's users section and user profile, wordpress username has dot in middle of the username. i suspect wordpress username (user.name) dont work with the plugin i use. therefore throwing 404 error. However if i can add a function to limit using dot in their user name i think will sort the problem, bu we need to makesure the email work fine when login in as emails definitely include a dot.

Comment: have you raised a bug with the members plugin? It's likely the rewrite rule regex never accounted for dots and the plugin can fix the issue directly